# localhost and 192.168.x.x over HTTPS for a-frame webVR development and local testing

Tags: ssl, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to develop a A-frame-based VR experience.

I can test it on my mac via `http://localhost` but can't do the same using mobile phone or VR headset via `http://192.168.1.123`.

The problem is that those browsers demand that the page is served over `HTTPS` rather than `HTTP`, otherwise it denies access to the device motion sensor, making testing impossible.

Using the following instructions, I managed to successfully have my VR web page served over  with a valid certificate.

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/
- https://github.com/mattdesl/budo/blob/master/docs/command-line-usage.md#ssl-and-https

But, that is not enough, mobile device and headset access the page over a local-wifi IP like `192.168.1.123` rather than localhost and the ssl certificate doesn't seem to work for those, even if i replace `localhost` by the correct IP when generating the domain key & certificates.

i guess each device browser would need to have its trusted store updated or something...

Would be curious to know how people solved their problem in their a-frame local development and testing flow.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer -- for Oculus Quest or Go browser development at least.

You can use the Chrome remote device debugging tools:
https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/oculus-browser/browser-remote-debugging/

Then setup port forwarding for the remote device:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server

This method allows you to sidestep the whole certificate thing since you can still use localhost:port to which the browser grants appropriate device permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use IP numbers, you want to include your local domain name into the certificate, like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/573216

Worked for me in a similar context.