# The future of A-frame, https?

Tags: https, aframe, webvr

So I been following A-frame WebVR and learning it since 2015. For me being a Web 'DESIGNER' since 2006, A-frame has been fairly easy to follow and design with, up until A-frame 1.0.0.

It seems now A-frame is becoming extremely cumbersome to work with. My design process was to always design on desktop using a web browser(like Firefox, Chrome, Edge)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cNBm.jpg) and check for the WEBVR through cardboard.
Now with the new updates assets like models and images will not load on any browser. Image assets for a-sky is extremly important in my design process.

And I read all the information about using a https connection, which shouldn't be necessary if your just in the design process. No other HTML application like Jquery, Bootstrap or ReactJS requires this. And I read about using your computer as a local server, again cumbersome, and extremely slow when designing PLUS it didn't work or it was so slow, its impossible to have the patience enough to design with.

I'm at the point of giving up on Aframe and moving on, just like Magic Leap.

So my question is whats the future of Aframe. Do the Aframe creators really expect 'DESIGNERS' to learn this stuff. The promise originally for Aframe was that it would be simple and USER FRIENDLY if your use to building with HTML, CSS and Javascript. It seems that it is gravitating away from that to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is enforced by browser vendors to access new APIs. It's not an A-Frame decision. WebXR, DeviceMotion and other APIs that A-Frame relies on are now only available over secure contexts (HTTPS) as [per browser policies](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features). Any site, library or framework using any of those APIs is subject to the same restrictions.

Tips:

- localhost is not subject to the HTTPS requirement so you can spawn a local server and develop via `localhost:port/`
- Look into [port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525215/localhost-and-192-168-x-x-over-https-for-a-frame-webvr-development-and-local-tes) to test on devices other than your dev machine
- Local development servers like [budo](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo) or [webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29772748/717508) have https modes using self signed certificates.
- [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) or code hosting platforms like [Glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe), [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@dmarcos/aframe#index.html) or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tag/aframe) provide https end points out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: You are welcome. If you can flag it as correct it will be appreciated.